# Enable one option group at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select name="campus">    
    <optgroup label="Northwest">
        <option value="1">Gary</option>
        <option value="2">Valparaiso</option>
        <option value="3">East Chicago</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="North Central">
        <option value="4">South Bend</option>
        <option value="5">Elkhart</option>
        <option value="6">Warsaw</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

I have multiple `<optgroup>`s in my dropdown. I am using the multiselect plugin. How can I restrict to select only one optgroup selection? That is, when one option in a group is selected, options in other groups should be disabled.

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried.

Comment: But the user should still be able to select multiple options from one group? If not, why use multi-select at all?

Comment: [Start here and please clarify](http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/3rTkJ/) That is, when you want it **restricted**. Do you have another checkbox? Or is this interpreting a value from a button or form element?

Comment: thanks for your update . yes i have another checkbox.  i am using multiselect plugin from erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos . when we select one optgroup others should disable, wen unselect again others should enable

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want something like this. Based on what you're asking for, how would you go about selecting from a different option group, if all the options are disabled?

```
$('select').on('change', function () {

    var selectedGroup = $('option:selected', this).parent();

    $('optgroup', this).not(selectedGroup).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rTkJ/3/)

Comment: How do I go back to the other county selection, perhaps on a misclick? (I know, the poster has provided less than ideal info lol)

Comment: thanks for your update . it works fine in jsfiddle, but not for my code, i am using multiselect plugin from http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos  . when we unselect the one opt group others should enable again

Comment: The demo page you linked to has application issues and is returning a server error. The answer I provided does answer your question, but as mentioned in my own question does not actually solve the problem. You need to update your post with your own relevant code, or perhaps write up your own demo fiddle so we know exactly what it is your are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the `element` that will be your **event handler**. We cannot code further without that.

*That is, what is determining if certain items are blocked or not?*

### Based on the info you provided without knowing your handler...

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/3rTkJ/2/

**HTML:**

```
<select name="campus" id="selCampus">    
    <optgroup label="Northwest" id="northWest">
        <option value="1">Gary</option>
        <option value="2">Valparaiso</option>
        <option value="3">East Chicago</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="North Central" id="northCentral">
        <option value="4">South Bend</option>
        <option value="5">Elkhart</option>
        <option value="6">Warsaw</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#selCampus').on('click', function(){
    $('#northCentral').hide();
});
```

Comment: it should be for dynamic, we may select any group. how to obtain that

Comment: One second... It's called a `paramter`

Comment: Still, I'm confused. Are you able to load your param into every HTML page or not?

Comment: thanks for your update . it works fine in jsfiddle, but not for my code, i am using multiselect plugin from erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos . when we unselect the one opt group others should enable again